# Pascal Dispose causes segmentation fault, yet I can't see why

Tags: class, pointers, segmentation-fault, runtime-error, delphi

```
program Project1;

type
  ob = class
    num: integer;
    constructor init(id: integer);
    destructor done();
  end;

  constructor ob.init(id: integer);
  begin
    self.num := id;
  end;

  destructor ob.done();
  begin
  end;

type
  plist = ^list;

  list = record
    myob: ^ob;
    Next: plist;
  end;
var start:plist;
begin

  start:=nil;
  new(start);
  start^.myob^:=ob.init(1);
  new(start^.next);
  start^.Next^.myob^:=ob.init(2);
  start^.next^.myob^.done();
  dispose(start^.Next);
  start^.myob^.done();
  dispose(start);

end.
```

this code results in
Error: Project project1 raised exception class 'External: SIGSEGV'. At address 405B32

when i try to run in debug i get the assembler screen popup and display

```
SYSTEM_$$_SYSGETMEM$LONGWORD$$POINTER(147)
00405B23 b890e44000               mov    $0x40e490,%eax
00405B28 e813080000               call   0x406340 <SYSTEM_$$_ENTERCRITICALSECTION$TRTLCRITICALSECTION>
00405B2D 89d8                     mov    %ebx,%eax
00405B2F 8b5004                   mov    0x4(%eax),%edx    <-error here
00405B32 8b92a0000000             mov    0xa0(%edx),%edx   <-or it might be here
00405B38 89500c                   mov    %edx,0xc(%eax)
00405B3B 8b5004                   mov    0x4(%eax),%edx
00405B3E 8982a0000000             mov    %eax,0xa0(%edx)
00405B44 b890e44000               mov    $0x40e490,%eax
00405B49 e802080000               call   0x406350 <SYSTEM_$$_LEAVECRITICALSECTION$TRTLCRITICALSECTION>
```

any help would be appreciated

how do i go about fixing this it seems to only happen when i try to use dispose
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not take a pointer of a class instance (a.k.a. object). A class instance is already a reference type:

```
plist = ^list;
list = record
  myob: ob;
  next: plist;
end;
```

Now you can do:

```
start^.myob := ob.init(1);
...
start^.next^.myob := ob.init(2);
```

and you will not get a crash anymore.

---

#### And now some remarks

It is not obligatory, but it is usual to use `Create` as the name for the constructor. And the destructor is generally called `Destroy`, and should be an override (of the virtual `TObject.Destroy`):

```
ob = class
  num: Integer;
  constructor Create(id: Integer);
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;
```

Also, it is usually a good idea to call the inherited constructor in the constructor and the inherited destructor in the destructor. Even if your class (implicitly) derives from `TObject` directly, this may not be the case in a less trivial program.

And finally, it is a good habit to never call the destructor directly. Use `Free` instead (this presupposes that your destructor is `override` and called `Destroy`). This checks for `Self` being `nil` first, which is good for class instances stored in other classes (if the outer class constructor fails, some of the contained classes may not have been initialized when the outer class' destructor is called).

Comment: thank you for your reply. So can i swap classes about ie instead of swapping the pointers to record can i also swap the classes of 2 records leaving the records in there original order. ( the code i use will need to do this as i will be playing with multiple lists of different types and also other structures)

Comment: sorry to answer my own question but i have tried swapping classes and i can so good solution thank you for the explanation.